# What is the reason for this compiler-error with long long int under Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The following code (simplified example, that triggers the error) doesn't compile with VS 2008:

```
#include <math.h>

void test()
{
    long long int val1 = 1;
    long long int val2 = 2;
    long long int val3 = abs<long long int>(val1 / val2);
}
```

That gives an compiler-error (C2062) on the third line - the type __int64 is unexpected. What is the reason for this error? How can it be avoided?

Comment: Post a complete compilable example (that means, show your includes).

Comment: Is long long allowed in VS 08? I have not used VS08, but long long was not present in older versions.

Comment: Uh, the file I encountered it has millions of includes, many of them internally to our project. But I could simplify it, so that I can reproduce the error. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @taskinoor: Seems to work. It doesn't complain about the use of long long int.

Comment: `long long` is supported as an alias for `__int64`. However, *if* there is an `abs` template it would be `std::abs` in `<cmath>` not in `<math.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `long long` version of `abs` isn't specified in the standard.

26.5/3 shows us `int` and `long` versions.

26.5/5 gives us `float`, `double`, `long double` overloads.

No other overloads appear to be required, I suspect because `long long` isn't mandated or supported on all compilers/systems.